# how do I add 2 event listeners inside a function and return which one happens?

Tags: javascript, function, dom-events

I am creating a javascript function ( function ask(question) ) that should return either 1 or -1 depending on what button the user presses.

Before I used a prompt :

```
function askOld(question)           
{   
    var answer;
    do{ 
        answer=prompt(question);
        if      (answer==="yes") return  1;
        else if (answer==="no") return -1;
    } while (1); 
}
```

which was ugly, but worked. It is important that all this is in a function, because I need to pass it to other functions, and store it in a variable.

Now I am trying to take off the prompt, and use eventListener.

```
function askTest(question)
{   
    var answer;
    document.querySelector('.domanda_intervista').textContent = question;
    document.querySelector('.button_no').addEventListener('click',function(){ 
        console.log("clicked no");
        answer="n";  
    });
    document.querySelector('.button_yes').addEventListener('click',function(){ 
        console.log("clicked yes");
        answer="y";  
    });

    if      (answer==="y") return  1;
    else if (answer==="n") return -1;

    return 2;
}
answerNow=askTest("is this true?");
console.log("answerNow",answerNow);
```

But this did not work. So I tried to call it continuously until the user pressed the button but that did not work out as expected...

```
do{
    answerNow=askTest("is this true?");
    console.log("answerNow",answerNow);    
}while (answerNow===2)
```

I looked for existing questions here, but none seem to answer this question. Can someone please help?
By the way, I come from Python, Javascript is new to me, so apologize if anything I am asking it obvious/dumb...

Comment: Code doesnt wait for an event listener to happen or complete. Nor can you return a value from one to the outer scope as there is nothing to return to as the outside code has already been executed. Execute / trigger the appropriate code from inside the event listeners

Comment: so how can I substitute the prompt for something more user friendly?

Comment: The use of jQuery doesn't matter, it is what is happening and the solution for it that matters. In both cases you want to do some asynchronous operation (an operation that doesn't block code from runnung). Ajax is async because some operation ( a network request) needs to happen before some code should be run. An event listener is async because some operation (a user interaction) needs to happen before some code needs to run. Therefore the actual problem and solution for both are the same.

Comment: Note there is a second linked duplicate about why modifying your variable in the event listener then trying to use it outside of it won't do what you expect. Both have solutions and explanations about what is going on. Either do the work needed in the event callbacks, or call some function that does it or use Promises.